# I want to make TextField required for the user

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I just want to make my TextField as required field, in which I am using Email and password to login for the user. Please let me know how can I make it required and if user don't fill it, how can I give him warning.

```
                        TextField (
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              email=value;
                            },
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                              filled: true,
                              hintText: "Email",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              )
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          TextField(
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              password=value;
                            },
                            style: const TextStyle(),
                            obscureText: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                              filled: true,
                              hintText: "Password",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              )
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: Wrap your field with Form and use TextFormField instead of TextField. So you can use the Global key for formate and check the state that the required field is fulfilled its condition or not. Flutter has an example please check this https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The esiest way to set a validation logic for the `TextField` in Flutter is to use `TextFormField` instead of `TextField` in combination with `Form` widget.

It provides you with a callback called `validator` which is called whenever you call `.validate()` method in the Form Key.

To learn more about using `Form` widget in Flutter along with `TextFormFiled` and validation, check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rn3XbBijy4).

Example for a condition in the validator to make the field required:

```
validator: (String? value) {
  if (value == null)
  {
    return 'This field is required';
  }
  return null;
},
```

**NOTE:**

If the `validator` callback returned a message, this means the message would be displayed in the `errorText` for the `TextFormField` and the `.validate()` method would return `false`.

If the `validator` callback returned null, this means that no errors and the `.validate()` method would return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

1. if user click on submit button then you can check for is email or password field is empty or not empty.